# error php function on a non-object

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have This php Function for get data for dynamic select box. i get country using form post method and put in dropdown menu. 
This function retrieve data from mysql :

```
   function drop_1($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM home WHERE date='$drop_var' ") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_2" id="drop_2">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['date'].'">'.$drop_2['data'].'</option>';
            }
 }
```

Now when i retireve data using jquery. I See this Error  :

**`fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\func.php on line 14`**

This Line 14 : `**$result = $db->query ($mysql);**`

What's Problem ? Thanks

Comment: Where is $db defined? There error states that you try to acces query in the object $db. But that $db is not an object. So how do you define $db?

Comment: When you want to create object , first you need class for that , where is your class ?

Comment: Can you give us the line where you typ: `$db = ......`

Comment: @SynerCoder : i dont care ! whats your mean : $db = ........

Comment: The whole point of your error is about how your defined `$db`. Is `$db` a object or not? Aka: is `$db` defined as followed: `$db = new MyClass();` or `$db = "string";` or `$db = 12;`. We need that line to discover your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`$db` belong to which class ? is there any class for `$db` object ?
make that class OR include from some where...

Comment: I Edited and Add $db function to my question

Comment: $db = new DB... something like this OR
directly use like $result = query($mysql);

Comment: whitout db function this worked : include_once('db.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE home='$drop_var'") 
 or die(mysql_error()); while($drop_3 = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))